# Which NPK range are lawn starter fertiliser?

Tags: lawn, grass, fertilizer

When watching videos on YouTube they talk about lawn starter fertilisers, where it is important to use such when seeding, so the new seeds doesn't burn.

But what NPK range are considered to be lawn starter fertilisers?

Or is there just some max values, that one should never exceed?

Comment: The NPK numbers just specify the *concentration* of the   nutrients. If you spread NPK 5-5-5 at say one ounce per square yard, that is exactly the same as 20-20-20 at 1/4 ounce per square yard. Fertilizers for non-professional use tend to have low NPK values simply because mistakes and/or uneven spreading are less serious. Professionals don't want to handle 5 tons of low-NPK fertilizer when 1 ton of high-NPK, used correctly, will do exactly the same job.

Comment: starters usually include a lot of other trace and micro nutrients. If there's already grass present, you should wait a week to fertilize so that the existing grass doesn't shoot up and shade the sprouts. If there's no grass, put the fertilizer down a few days before seed if you want to eliminate burn risk.